# How to run bdd cucumber 5.6 without giving feature and glue path in test runner file

Tags: java, cucumber, bdd, test-runner

I am using the cucumber-java 5.6 version. As per this version we can run scripts without having to give feature and glue path in the test runner, tried various options but it is not working.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Sooo.... What did you read, what did you try, and what didn't work? Might be good to spend some time researching how to ask a question. Right now none can help you.

Comment: Will try from next time